# Django REST Viewsets - Cannot delete with custom queryset

Tags: django, view, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST and I have a question about viewsets. I can't seem to create a viewset (with a custom query) where deleting a record is still possible. So I use another viewset which is exactly the same, but without the custom query to delete records. This way it works, but I'm still wondering if there's a way to combine it into one as this seems like a hack.

**List my employees, DELETE doesn't work with this viewset. 404 Not found error.**

```
class MyEmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CustomUser.objects.filter(employer=self.request.user.pk)
```

**So I use this viewset to ADD/DELETE.**

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(employer=self.request.user)
```

**The urls**

```
router.register('manager/myemployees', MyEmployeeViewSet)
router.register('manager/employees', EmployeeViewSet)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the employer that deletes the custom user? Since here the `get_queryset` thus limits the `CustomUser`s, and this means only the employer can delete the object (not even the user itself).

Comment: Yes basically the employer gets to see its employees' user accounts, can edit and delete them, and create more employee user accounts.